# HTML tags in SRT files produced by ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, .srt

What I do:

```
$ ffmpeg -i a.mkv -c:s srt b.srt
```

The resulting file contains HTML tags, is there a way to avoid that?

On a side note, where can I find the list of... what do they call it... encoders? I simply tried `srt` for the name and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of *srt* try to use *text*:

```
$ ffmpeg -i a.mkv -c:s text b.srt
```

[(source)](https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-December/029668.html)

For a list of all codecs use:

```
ffmpeg -encoders
```

You can check the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for more options.

Comment: Well, the documentation is apparently rather incomplete. Some things can only be learned from the [code](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/n4.3.1/libavcodec/srtenc.c#L306-L344). Like, what's the difference between the srt encoders.